# Periodic function without primitive period

Tags: functions

I have a problem finding an example of a periodic function that does not have a primitive period. Can someone give me such example or explain how to find such function?

Comment: A trivial one is a constant function.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2942016/function-with-arbitrary-small-period

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, you should upvote all the useful answers and accept the answer that is most useful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One obvious example is the constant function, for which every real number is a period.

Another example would be the function $1_{\mathbb Q}$ (the indicator function for the set $\mathbb Q$), defined as

$$\begin{cases}1 &\text{if } x\in\mathbb Q\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
for which every *rational* number is a period.

Answer (score 0):

The set of all periods of a function is an abelian group. Not every non trivial abelian group has a generator. The rationals under addition is an example with no generator. Consider two real numbers to be equivalent if their difference is a rational number. Any non constant function that is constant on the equivalence classes of this relation will be a periodic function with no primitive period because all rationals are periods. Of course, such a function is not continuous anywhere.